# Substr e Preg_match quando utilizar uma ou outra?

Tags: php, string

Dúvidas sobre as  funções `substr e preg_match/preg_match_all.`

- Quando irei utilizar uma ou outra?
- Ambas retiram partes dos textos, só que `preg_match` retira através de
  expressões regulares correto?
- Poderiam me dar exemplos de aplicações destas funções e as impressões
  dos resultados para meu melhor entendimento?
- Teria como eu extrair o mesmo com expressões regulares só que elas
  são mais recomendadas quando são grandes conteúdos de string,
  correto?

## Meu código:

```
  $arbitro= "Dentista   Marcovs Salgado de Rorgernaldo Henrique - MG";
    $posicao=strpos("-");
    $posicao=$posicao-2;
    $nomeDentista=substr($arbitro,0,$posicao);
    echo $nomeDentista;
    //impressão desejada por mim
    Dentista Marcovs Salgado de Rorgernaldo Henrique
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strpos () é 3-16 vezes mais rápido do que preg_match ()   [**Fonte**](http://we-love-php.blogspot.com.br/2014/03/strpos-vs-pregmatch-vs-stripos.html)

Para impressão desejada por você o código deve ser assim  [**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/q5EDtI):

```
$arbitro= "Dentista   Marcovs Salgado de Rorgernaldo Henrique - MG";
$posicao=strpos($arbitro,"-");
$posicao=$posicao-1;
$nomeDentista=substr($arbitro,0,$posicao);
echo $nomeDentista;
```

> Note que a função   [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) requer 2 parâmetros.  `strpos($procurarAqui, $procurarOque)`
>
> No seu caso `strpos($arbitro,"-")`

**A função substr()** serve para obtermos uma substring. Esta função possui 3 parâmetros sendo o terceiro opicional.

Parâmetro 1: A string completa de onde está a substring

Parâmetro 2: Número inteiro que indica a posição onde a substring começa

Parâmetro 3 (opcional): O tamanho (número de caracteres) da substring

Por padrão, a função substr() obtém a substring do ponto inicial determinado até o final da string. Mas é possível delimitarmos ainda mais a substring se utilizarmos o 3º parâmetro para indicar quantos caracteres desejamos obter a partir do ponto inicial. Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
  $string = "stackoverflow.com";
  $substr1 = substr($string, 5);      // overflow.com
  $substr2 = substr($string, 5, 9);  // over
```

**É possível utilizar a função preg_match** para saber se uma determinada sequência de caracteres existe em um texto. Vamos supor que você vai pegar algum texto de qualquer fonte e queira saber se existe algum email nesse texto. Veja o código:

```
$subject = "MSeu email é jose@dominio.com";
$pattern = '/([-.a-zA-Z]{1,30})@([-.a-zA-Z]{1,30})([.]{1})([-.a-zA-Z]{1,10})/';
$result = preg_match($pattern, $subject);
```

No código acima, $subject é o texto onde você fará a pesquisa, $pattern é uma expressão regular (ER) criada para  casar um email.
O retorno da função preg_match para a variável $result são:

```
0 – caso a ER não case com nenhuma parte do texto
1 – caso a ER case com alguma parte do texto
```

Com este exemplo, você pode checar se um usuário digitou um email válido em seu cadastro.

Uma vez entendido como se utiliza a função  `preg_match` fica fácil entender a função `preg_match_all`, pois ela tem o mesmo comportamento, com pequenas diferenças, como as flags utilizadas e o seu modo de busca, que é feito de uma maneira global no texto. A função `preg_match` foi desenvolvida para assim que encontrar o padrão necessário, será retornado e não será feita busca no restante do texto.

A função preg_match_all() retornará um número inteiro com a quantidade de ocorrências encontradas pela expressão regular.

A função aceita 5 parâmetros, sendo 3 obrigatórios e 2 opcionais.

$resultado = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

- $pattern será a expressão regultar
- $subject será o texto que a expressão irá pesquisar
- $matches será um array com as ocorrências

  [**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/1yXfUH)

> Caso você não precise utilizar ER e queira apenas verificar se uma string está dentro de outra você deveria usar outras funções como o strpos ou strstr, visto que sãos mais rápidas.